# confusion about the past perfect continuous

Tags: grammaticality, past-tense, perfect-aspect, continuous-aspect

I'm writing the profile section of my résumé/CV.

I'm hesitating about the proper verb form:

> During my work experience I have applied engineering methods to solve
>   problems.
>
> I have been involved in the development of new products.

Is it right? Or should I use "I have been applying engineering methods" instead?

More information:
I still do apply that methods.
I'm not involved in the development anymore.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

‘I have been applying engineering methods’ would better convey the fact that you are continuing to do so.

If you were involved in the development of new products in the past, but are not involved any more, it might be preferable to write ‘I was involved . . .’ and then give more details about when and how long you were involved.

Comment: OK, the first example is clear for me now, I'll use your suggested " I have being applying..."

Comment: The second example...  I mean I've been involved in the development several times, in different periods, and I could do it again.

Comment: Then there's no harm in saying so.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to say that you still apply those methods then you can use "I have been applying engineering methods".You should use present perfect continuous form when it is ongoing event like in your case.It would be better if you use some time frame with it like for some time.

Comment: Can someone point out the probable reason for downvote?It is not a rant.I just want to know if I said something wrong.